# Dropdown to listView

Tags: listview, flutter, drop-down-menu, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `DropdownMenu` which is working fine, but instead of that I need a `ListView`, I just cannot convert it. The `DropdownMenu` looks like this:

```
  // Create the List of devices to be shown in Dropdown Menu
  List<DropdownMenuItem<BluetoothDevice>> _getDeviceItems() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<BluetoothDevice>> items = [];
    if (_devicesList.isEmpty) {
      items.add(
          DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(allTranslations.text(StringConstant.none)),
      )
      );
    } else {
      _devicesList.forEach((device) {
        items.add(
            DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(device.name),
          value: device,
        ));
      });
    }
    return items;
  }
```

And I called it like this

```
DropdownButton(
          items: _getDeviceItems(),
          onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _device = value),
          value: _device,
        ),
```

I tried to convert it to a listTile like this:

```
// Create the List of devices to be shown in Dropdown Menu
  List<ListTile> _getDeviceListTiles() {
    List<ListTile> items = [];
    if (_devicesList.isEmpty) {
      items.add(
          ListTile(
            title: Text(allTranslations.text(StringConstant.none)),
      )
      );
    } else {
      _devicesList.forEach((device) {
        items.add(
            ListTile(
          title: Text(device.name),
        ));
      });
    }
    return items;
  }
```

as you might see, I managed to convert it to a list of `ListTile` but the problem is I do not now how to call this list in a `ListView` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restructure your code or you could use these two simple ways for your existing code.

1. Simple ListView

```
ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  children: _getDeviceListTiles()
);
```

2. ListView.builder()

```
ListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  itemCount: _getDeviceListTiles().length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return _getDeviceListTiles()[index];
  }
);
```